# Passing Range#step multiple arguments

Tags: ruby

Ruby docs show that [Range#step](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-step) accepts one argument. It appears to be used for iterating over a range in increments of a number passed to `step`.

```
(0..100).step(5) { |x| puts x }
```

should produce:

```
0
5
10
15
...
```

In examples of the sieve of eratosthenes, people are passing `Range#step` what appears to be two arguments as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241691/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-ruby):

```
(primes[index] * 2).step(primes.last, primes[index]) do
```

What is going on here? What is happening when you pass `step` two arguments? When I test it with something like:

```
(0..100).step(5,10) { |x| puts x }
```

I get:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication doesn't return a Range, so that isn't [Range#step](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Range.html#method-i-step) -- it's [Numeric#step](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Numeric.html#method-i-step), which takes an endpoint and a step amount.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike what you claim that the method is `Range#step`, the one that you mentioned taking two arguments is [`Numeric#step`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Numeric.html#method-i-step). The first argument is the limit and the second argument is the step.