# Code Optimization - Generating Prime Numbers

Tags: ruby, algorithm, primes

I am trying to write a code for the following problem:

Input

The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

Output

For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.

Sample Input:

```
2
1 10
3 5
```

Sample Output:

```
2
3
5
7

3
5
```

My code:

```
def prime?(number)
    return false if number == 1
    (2..number-1).each do |n|            
        return false if number % n == 0             
    end 
    true    
end

t = gets.strip.to_i
for i in 1..t
    mi, ni = gets.strip.split(' ')
    mi = mi.to_i
    ni = ni.to_i

    i = mi
    while i <= ni
        puts i if prime?(i)
        i += 1
    end


    puts "\n"
end
```

The code is running fine, only problem I am having is that it is taking a lot of time when run against big input ranges as compared to other programming languages.

Am I doing something wrong here? Can this code be further optimized for faster runtime?

I have tried using a for loop, normal loop, creating an array and then printing it.
Any suggestions.

Comment: "is taking a lot of time" Give us numbers. How slow is it?

Comment: You have a potential bug in your code here relating to the reuse of `i` for the inner loop. It would probably be good to use a different variable for either loop. I'll make the change in my code sample below.

Comment: @mast i don't have time ... but it is slower than six seconds as this is a challenge on spoj.com and when I submit my solution it says time limit exceeded. Time limit there is 6 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return true if the number is 2, false if the number is evenly divisible by 2.

Start iterating at 3, instead of 2. Use a step of two.

Iterate up to the square root of the number, instead of the number minus one.

```
def prime?(number)
  return true if number == 2
  return false if number <= 1 or number % 2 == 0
  (3..Math.sqrt(number)).step(2) do |n|
    return false if number % n == 0
  end
  true
end
```

This will be much faster, but still not very fast, as @Technation explains.

Here's how to do it using the Sieve of Eratosthenes [built into](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html) Ruby. You'll need to precompute all the primes up to the maximum maximum, which will be very quick, and then select the primes that fall within each range.

```
require 'prime'

ranges = Array.new(gets.strip.to_i) do
  min, max = gets.strip.split.map(&:to_i)
  Range.new(min, max)
end

primes = Prime.each(ranges.map(&:max).max, Prime::EratosthenesGenerator.new)

ranges.each do |range|
  primes.each do |prime|
    next if prime < range.min 
    break if prime > range.max
    puts prime
  end

  primes.rewind
  puts "\n"
end
```

Here's how the various solutions perform with the range 50000 200000:

- Your original prime? function: 1m49.639s
- My modified prime? function: 0m0.687s
- Prime::EratosthenesGenerator: 0m0.221s

The more ranges being processed, the faster the Prime::EratosthenesGenerator method should be.

Comment: Have tried doing this as well. Still not fast enough

Comment: Note that this is still inefficient, since it checks for _every number_ whether it is a prime or not. You might have gotten rid of one loop, but you can actually save *two* loops by doing `Prime.each(100) {|prime| p prime }` as the ruby documentation explains: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html

Comment: @Technaton I'm just replacing the `prime?` function. If there are other inefficiencies in the OP's code, I don't know why you're addressing them in the comments of my answer rather than in your own answer. That being said, the OP is trying to find prime numbers within a given range, but `Prime.each` enumerates primes starting at 2, so I don't think it can be used here.

Comment: @Technaton If you were suggesting I precompute the primes using Prime::EratosthenesGenerator, I've gone ahead and done that. Thanks.

Comment: They all work but I don't know why but when I submit the codes on spoj.com, it always says time limit exceeded. Anyways after employing my whole day on this problem, I have moved on. Thank you mwp @Technaton. Actually learned a lot today. I had never even heard of these sieve algorithms. Will be reading more about them and such algo's. Any good reading place you guys could suggest for such things.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is slower than some other languages, depending on what language you compare it to; certainly slower than C/C++. But your problem is not the language (although it influences the run-time behavior), but your way of finding primes. There are many better algorithms for finding primes, such as the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or the [Sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin). You might also read the “[Generating Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes)” page on Wikipedia and follow the links there.

By the way, for the Sieve of Eratosthenes, there is even a ready-to-use [piece of code on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241691/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-ruby#432889). I'm sure a little bit of googling will turn up implementations for other algorithms, too.

Since your problem is finding primes within a certain range, this is the Sieve of Eratosthenes code found at the above link modified to suit your particular problem:

```
def better_sieve_upto(first, last)
  sieve = [nil, nil] + (2..last).to_a
  sieve.each do |i|
    next unless i
    break if i*i > last
    (i*i).step(last, i) {|j| sieve[j] = nil }
  end
  sieve.reject {|i| !i || i < first}
end
```

Note the change from "sieve.compact" to a complexer "sieve.reject" with a corresponding condition.

Comment: `better_sieve_upto(1, 10)` returns `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, so something is not quite right with your solution.

Comment: This function as it is wont work. You will have to change back line2: ```s = (2..last).to_a``` then change second last line: ```s.compact!``` then add below second last line: ```s.reject! {|x| x < first}```

Comment: You are quite right; there are some things amiss here. I've updated it.