# Speeding up greatest prime factor program in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, performance, primes

A simple program to find the greatest prime factor of a number in Ruby, made up of 2 methods:

```
def is_prime?(n)
  (2..n).select {|number| n % number == 0}.length == 1 ? true : false
end

def prime_factors(number)
  (1..number).select {|m| number % m == 0 && is_prime?(m) == true}.max
end
```

It works fine for small numbers like 100. However, I'm trying to solve the problem on Project Euler, which uses the number 600851475143. When trying this the problem will not even run and I end up canceling it after about a minute.

How can I alter this to increase performance?

Comment: your second method name is misleading.

Answer (score 5):

Use Ruby's [Prime#prime_division](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html) method:

```
require 'prime'

Prime.prime_division(600851475143).max_by(&:first).first
  #=> 6857
```

Three steps:

```
a = Prime.prime_division(600851475143)
  #=> [[71, 1], [839, 1], [1471, 1], [6857, 1]]
  # Note (71**1)*(839**1)*(1471**1)*(6857**1) #=> 600851475143  
b = a.max_by(&:first)
  #=> [6857, 1] 
b.first
  #=> 6857
```

Comment: For very large numbers, Prime::EratosthenesGenerator is likely faster (e.g. `Prime.prime_division(600851475143, Prime::EratosthenesGenerator.new`) — no, I take that back, it looks like the default generator is faster. Maybe 600851475143 isn't very large? :-)

Comment: In your explanation you've used `max` as your final step whereas you've used `first` in your original solution.

Comment: @mwp , Cary, idk, at what point does one just type http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=greatest+prime+factor+of+600851475143 lol

Comment: @גלעדברקן If you just need a one-off to find the largest prime factor of a number, Alpha is fine, but if you are finding several prime factors as part of a larger process, and need to do so programmatically, here we are.

Comment: @mwp sure, I'm half kidding, but for Euler problems, isn't the point trying to come up with somewhat of a fuller sense of the algorithmic solution?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Ah, good point. I missed the Project Euler part of the OP. I suppose in that context, it's a little silly to be using Ruby's `Prime#prime_division`!

Answer (score 3):

There is a way of factoring which is more efficient and which also finds only prime factors, eliminating the need to test for primeness. Skip to the end to see it or read through to see how I got there.

I refactored your solution so it would be easier to think about, extracting a `factors` method, removing unnecessary explicit uses of booleans and renaming some things:

```
def greatest_prime_factor(n)
  factors(n).select { |c| prime?(c) }.max
end

def factors(n)
  (1..n).select { |c| n % c == 0 }
end

def prime?(n)
  (2..n).count { |c| n % c == 0 } == 1
end
```

There is an inefficiency in `factors`: even after we know that a number c (for "candidate") is a factor, we test numbers greater than n/c. To fix that, when we find a factor, divide n by it before we look for the next factor:

```
def factors(n)
  if n == 1
    []
  else
    f = (2..n).find { |c| n % c == 0 }
    [f] + factors(n / f)
  end
end
```

(The other methods stay the same.) With that change, the whole program factors 600851475143 in a few ms (not counting Ruby process startup time).

Why was that change so effective? It's not only that `factors` was slow; the original program spent about 75% of its time in `prime?`. But while the original version of `factors` returned all of a number's factors, both prime and nonprime, the new version of `factors` only returns primes. (This is because it accumulates the smallest remaining factor, and the smallest prime factor is always smaller than the smallest nonprime factor.) So not only are we now factoring faster, we also have less factors to test for primeness, and the factors we are testing for primeness are smaller and take less time to test for primeness.

What's more, since `factors` now returns primes we don't need to test primeness at all, so let's rename `factors` to make it clear that it returns primes and eliminate `prime?`:

```
def greatest_prime_factor(n)
  prime_factors(n).max
end

def prime_factors(n)
  if n == 1
    []
  else
    f = (2..n).find { |c| n % c == 0 }
    [f] + prime_factors(n / f)
  end
end
```

As well as being shorter, that's faster yet, factoring 600851475143 in less than 1 ms (again, not counting Ruby process startup time) on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your `is_prime?` method:

1. Ruby conventions suggest you name it `prime?`, not `is_prime?`
2. It doesn't correctly handle cases where `n` is one or less
3. `#select` will keep iterating after it has found a match; for best performance it should break out of the loop as quickly as possible
4. A quick optimization is to return false for any number that is evenly divisible by two
5. Your loop can start at three and only iterate over odd numbers
6. Your loop only has to iterate up to the square root of `n`, instead of `n`

There was a recent, similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39294252/1021515), and I published a much faster `prime?` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39294433/1021515).

Comment: Where you say you *published* a faster method, by clicking on the link I was expecting to be taken to an esteemed journal. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland LOL! I was wrestling with what verb to use there. Are you suggesting Stack Overflow answers aren't highly esteemed? ;)

Comment: Let's just say that I am not inclined to add my SO answers to my *curriculum vitae*.

Comment: @CarySwoveland But they're peer-reviewed!