# Displaying factors of a number prompted by a user

Tags: ruby, factors

I am trying to create a program that prompts a user to input a number and then checks if its a prime number. I am also trying to get it to display the factors if it isn't a prime number.

I managed to create the first part of the program, but I am struggling with the last part.

```
def prime(n)
 is_prime = true
  for i in 2..n-1
   if n % i == 0
   is_prime = false
end
 end

if is_prime
 puts "#{n} is a prime number"
else
 puts "#{n} is not a prime number =>" 

end
 end


prime(n)
```

At this step:

```
puts "#{n} is not a prime number =>"
```

I want to incorporate the displaying of factors, let's say the number is 8

8 is not a prime number => 1, 2, 4, 8

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
def factors(n)
  (1..n/2).select{|e| (n%e).zero?}.push(n)
end
```

factors(8) => [1,2,4,8]

and your last step will look as:

```
puts "#{n} is not a prime number =>#{factors(n).join(',')}"
```

By the way: for check if number is prime, advice to use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241691/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-ruby).

Comment: You can speed up your factor-finding code by 100%. You only need to check the first half (`c / 2`) numbers. The second half will never result in a factor (except for `c` itself)

Comment: Also, use `select` instead of `map + compact`. Will look much cleaner.

Comment: Hi, that worked, thank you! But would you mind explaining what select, join and .zero? do? I am relatively new to ruby :/

Comment: Hey, no prob:
1. (1..n/2) generates Range class from 1 to n/2
2. select does select from Range elements, where n%e == 0 
zero? method returns true, if number == 0; select method returns array
3. push(n) adds to array element(n)